# QML connect() passing extra arguments

Tags: qml, connection, qt-signals

I want to connect `signal_A(C)` from `itemA` to `function_B(currentIndex,C)` from `itemB`.

How do I connect them? When its `signal_A(C) -> function_B(C)` it will be:
 `itemA.signal_A.connect(itemB.function_B);`

But I am not sure how to link them when there is an extra argument on the slot. Something like this:
`item_A.signal_A.connect(item_B.function_B(currentIndex, C));`

Comment: By the way, I am connecting at Component.onCompleted, I prefer to avoid using Connections method.

Comment: Is there a reason, why you avoid using declarative `Connections`? Could you please show some more code, to put your connections in a context? Something more like a [MCVE](/help/mvce).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a wrapper function at a place that has access to the `currentIndex`

```
function wrapFunctionB(C) {
    return function_B(currentIndex, C)
}
```

and then connect to this function:

```
item_A.signal_A.connect(where.ever.wrapFunctionB)
```

If the place where you connect has access to all parameters, you can also connect it to an anonymous function:

```
item_A.signal_A.connect(function(C) { function_B(from.where.ever.currentItem, C) })
```